# Session data not saved after reload page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to create a login panel from my index page. Login data will be send by ajax call. If user name and password is correct then I am setting the userdata in session and reloading the index page at ajax success. I have included config file in all page where I have written session_start() method So that session_start() can be available in all page. I have also checked phpinfo, session support is enabled. I have also checked in ajax php page the values are set in session but after reloading the index page session array is empty.

Please help me and guide me how I can solve this issue.

This is my `config.php` file

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysql_host = "****";
$mysql_user = "****";
$mysql_password = "****";
$mysql_db = "****";
$link = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or die('');
mysql_select_db("$mysql_db")or die("cannot select DB");
include 'includes/user_model.php';
$fgmembersite = new FGMembersite();
$fgmembersite->InitDB($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_db);
?>
```

user_model.php is the handling the db checking and session set.

```
function Login()
{
    if(empty($_POST['Email']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $username = trim($_POST['Email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  //  if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;

    return true;
}

function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
 {
    $this->tablename='users';
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }          
    $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);
    $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
    $qry = "Select * from $this->tablename where username='$username' OR email = '$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and active_status=1";

    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
        return false;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];
    $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['type_id'] = $row['type_id'];

    return true;
  }
```

ajax.php

```
   <?php
   include 'includes/config.php';
   if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {
    if($fgmembersite->Login()) {
      echo 1;
    }
  else {
   echo $fgmembersite->error_message;    
   }
  }
```

In Index.php I am submitting the login form by jQuery:

```
   <script> $(document).ready(function()
   {
$("button#login").click(function()

    {$("#ErrorMessages").hide(); 

     $("#ErrorMessages").html("");            

     var username = $("#username").val();            

     var pwd = $("#password").val();            

     if(username =='' || pwd == '')                

     $("#ErrorMessages").show();                

     $("#ErrorMessages").html("Inavalid Username or Password");                  

     $.ajax({  type: "POST",

               url: "loginChk.php",         

               data: $('form.login').serialize(),               

               success: function(msg)

               { if(msg == 1){

                 // $(location).attr('href','index.php');                            
                location.reload();
               }                            

               else

               {   

                $("#ErrorMessages").show();                     

                $("#ErrorMessages").html(msg);                              

                }},         

                error: function(){                            

                $("#ErrorMessages").html(msg);              

                return false;}                  

                });                        

                return false; });});

                </script>
```

Comment: How people will help you without see your code ?

Comment: Are you setting all your session variables before any text output (like <html>)?

Comment: Are you including the file with session_start() before any other output?

Comment: This code doesn't help me much. Also, next time just edit your question, it's much easier to read that way.
Maybe you have a space before `<?` ?
Some editors also put `dtž` on the beginning of file if it's `UTF-8` (like Notepad++). Go into settings and change encoding to `UTF-8 without BOM`.

Comment: I have added code , please check it may help you

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code, except those spaces on the beginning of `ajax.php`. You must be absolutely sure nothing is sent before `$_SESSION` variables are set.

Comment: I have figure out the problem , its a session_save_path issue of server. After I have specified  session_save_path("/cgi-bin/tmp"); before session_start() the session issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the problem , its a session_save_path issue on server. After I have specified path before session start in my config file.

```
session_save_path("/home/users/web/***/cgi-bin/tmp"); // path of the directory used to save session data. 
session_start();
```

session is now working.

for reference check this [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) info.